# How to sum dinamilcy calculated values in each row?

Tags: mysql

I need your advice in this scenario.

Having the following SQL query

```
SELECT 
    MONTHNAME(r.date_of_application) month_name,
    MONTH(r.date_of_application) month,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN status = 'pending' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) pending,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN status = 'attended' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) attended,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN status = 'absent' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) absent,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN status = 'canceled' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) canceled
FROM
    request r
        INNER JOIN
    user u ON u.id = r.user_id
GROUP BY month_name , month
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

I get this result

```
+------------+-------+---------+----------+--------+----------+
| month_name | month | pending | attended | absent | canceled |
+------------+-------+---------+----------+--------+----------+
| October    |    10 |       4 |        1 |      0 |        1 |
+------------+-------+---------+----------+--------+----------+
```

Now I want to sum the values of the columns `pending`, `attended`, `absent` and `canceled` an add the result in a new column `total`.

This is the expected result.

```
+------------+-------+---------+----------+--------+----------+-------+
| month_name | month | pending | attended | absent | canceled | total |
+------------+-------+---------+----------+--------+----------+-------+
| October    |    10 |       4 |        1 |      0 |        1 |    6 |
+------------+-------+---------+----------+--------+----------+-------+
```

This query could have many results

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your total in the expected output does not equal the sum of the components.

Comment: I just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `COUNT(*)` aggregation term to capture the entire count of all statuses:

```
SELECT 
    MONTHNAME(r.date_of_application) month_name,
    MONTH(r.date_of_application) month,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'pending'  THEN 1 END) pending,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'attended' THEN 1 END) attended,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'absent'   THEN 1 END) absent,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'canceled' THEN 1 END) canceled,
    COUNT(*) total
FROM request r
INNER JOIN user u
    ON u.id = r.user_id
GROUP BY
    month_name , month
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Note: If you want the `total` to include only the four `status` values which you are currently tallying, then use a conditional aggregation:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN status IN ('pending', 'attended', 'absent', 'cancelled')
           THEN 1 END) AS total
```

Comment: I guess sum(status='pending') does the same thing

Comment: @Strawberry 'Tis better to guess and be wrong then to never have guessed at all.  And it's better to avoid non ANSI standard extensions, unless using them would provide some major benefit such as performance.